How to reduce build time for a Compose Multiplatform project in Android Studio?
I'm developing a Compose Multiplatform project targeting both Android and iOS, and I'm experiencing long build times, especially during Kotlin compilation for multiple platforms (Android and iOS). The build process frequently shows warnings, like those in the image below:

Some points to consider:
I'm using compileSdk = 35 for Android, but I get warnings suggesting that a newer Android Gradle plugin should be used.
The iOS build (compiling Kotlin for Arm64, X64, and Simulators) is especially slow.
I get a large number of warnings during compilation, which might be contributing to the long build times.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far without much improvement
Environment:

Android Studio Koala
Compose Multiplatform
Targeting Android and iOS (Arm64, X64)

Any advice on how to optimize the build times would be highly appreciated!

How powerful is your build system (CPU, RAM, SSD)? In case you are using Windows, have you excluded the project from Defender scanning as suggested by Android Studio?

Apple M2 Pro; RAM (32GB); SSD and i excluded the project from Defender scanning

According to the compatibility guide https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-compatibility-guide.html#version-compatibility currently the maximum AGP version is 8.5, which is meant to be used with compileSdk 34.
